# Get theme RGB color

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1,In my project dataTable exporter option used.When I clicked export pdf using poi .My doubt is current theme RGB color value get  pass through pdf method because  theme changed to press export button that theme color RGB value  set header text  background color to export pdf
**My doubt is how to get RGB value of theme color and pass through poi method?**

Comment: I have no clue what you mean

Comment: I need get current Theme Color to set background color of header cell for pdf and excel.So I using POI Api to export pdf and excel get theme color to pass poi Api method to set header color

Comment: With javascript you can read the css on the client. Maybe use that to pass it to the server.